# Proxy ProGet nuget repository/feed in Nexus OSS 3?

Tags: windows, proxy, nexus, proget

I have two windows machines, one running [Nexus OSS 3](http://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype) and the other running  [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget).

Now I would like to create a [nuget proxy repository](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/nuget.html#nuget-proxy) in Nexus that points to one of the feeds/repositories I have in ProGet. I have followed this guide: [nuget proxy repository](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/nuget.html#nuget-proxy) where I basically copied the **nuget.org-proxy** proxy configuration that comes by default when you install Nexus OSS 3.

But I keep getting this error from command line

```
GET http://mynexus:8082/repository/tools-proxy/Packages(Id='x',Version='1.1.1')
GET http://mynexus:8082/repository/tools-proxy/Packages(Id='x',Version='1.1.1.0')
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '1.1.1' of package 'x'.
   at NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
```

And the Nexus web log:

```
2016-05-25 20:13:28,252+0200 INFO  [qtp1305498137-264] admin org.sonatype.nexus.rapture.internal.security.SessionServlet - Deleting session for user: admin
2016-05-25 20:13:32,971+0200 ERROR [qtp1305498137-282] *UNKNOWN org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet - Failed to invoke action method: coreui_Repository.coreui_Repository_readStatus, java-method: org.sonatype.nexus.coreui.RepositoryComponent.readStatus
org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException: The current Subject is not authenticated.  Access denied.
    at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthenticatedAnnotationHandler.assertAuthorized(AuthenticatedAnnotationHandler.java:53) [na:na]
    at org.a
```

When I run nuget install on a package **X** specifying the proxy repository URL as source:

```
nuget install x -Version 1.1.1 -Source http://mynexus:8082/repository/tools-proxy -Pre -NoCache -Verbosity detailed
```

That package indeed exists in the original ProGet feed and if I specify the direct/non-proxy feed instead the install works fine:

```
nuget install x -Version 1.1.1 -Source http://myproget:8181/repository/tools -Pre -NoCache -Verbosity detailed
GET http://myproget:8181/nuget/Tools/Packages(Id='x',Version='1.1.1')
GET http://myproget:8181/nuget/Tools/package/x/1.1.1
Installing 'x 1.1.1'.
Successfully installed 'x 1.1.1'.
```

I have tried with nuget version 2.8 and 3.4.

My ProGet server is configured with Built-In authentication:

[image]

Anonymous have download access:

[image]

Why do I get this access error when Anonymous have download access on my ProGet server?